# Ubuntu на ноут, проблема с WiFi

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, linux

Здравствуйте.

Не могу настроить wifi. Все нужные команды ввел.

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcpwpa-driver wextwpa-ssid <имя_точки_доступа>wpa-ap-scan 1wpa-proto RSNwpa-pairwise CCMPwpa-group CCMPwpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSKwpa-psk <hex_ключ> auto wlan0.
```

Сеть в NetMan отсутствует, но в терминале после сканировании сети она есть. Драйвер установлен! Сетевая карта - Atheros. WiFi на Win7 работает. После  перезагрузки `/etc/init.d/networking` выводятся следующие сообщения

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

> `Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces * Reconfiguring network interfaces...                                          RTNETLINK answers: No such processioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argumentioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argumentwpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to startrun-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Comment: ifconfig -aВ студию...

Comment: пока не будет предоставлен результат ifconfig и говорить не о чем :)

Comment: У меня Broadcom B43, в Ubunte для неё дров нету из коробки (хотя вроде бы должны подтянуться после установки). Если у вас то же, могу подкинуть решение.

Comment: http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/6612310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня решилось добавлением строки `blacklist acer_wmi` в `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo modprobe -r wlsudo modprobe brcmsmacsudo rfkill unblock allrfkill list all
```

В убунту слабоват. Но у меня включается `wi-fi` после введения этих строк. Правда приходится вводить при каждом включении.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне кажется, проблема в том, что вы указываете `wpa-driver wext`, который является универсальным драйвером. Попробуйте указать вместо `wpa-driver wext - wpa-driver madwifi` (это драйвер именно Atheros).

Answer (score 0):

Кто как, а я точку доступа на стационарном компе с WiFi карточкой делал через hostapd. Пользовался вот этим: http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=61834.0 и вот этим: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/wifi_ap . Ну, с некоторыми изменениями. Три года работало, потом надоело жечь электричество, купил дешёвый Wi-Fi роутер, и доволен!